# Why my nested recursive modal mounting each time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, performance, recursion

I am creating a side hierarchy for controlling all my `Modal` usage in the app

```
import ReactNativeModal, { ModalProps } from 'react-native-modal';


export const ModalsProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const [modals, setModals] = useState<IModal[]>([]);
  const [modalsMap, setModalsMap] = useState({});
  const isModalsExist = useMemo<boolean>(() => !!modals.length, [!!modals.length]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ isModalsExist });
  }, [isModalsExist]);
  
  const MoadlComponent: ComponentType<{ idx: number }> = ({ idx }) => {
    const isNextExist = useMemo<boolean>(
      () => modals.length - 1 > idx,
      [modals.length - 1 > idx]
    );
    const { name, modalProps, props } = useMemo<IModal>(() => modals[idx], [idx]);
    const MyModal = useMemo<ComponentType>(() => modalsMap[name], [name]);

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log({ idx });
    }, []);

    return (
      <ReactNativeModal {...modalProps}>
        <MyModal {...props} />
        {isNextExist && <MoadlComponent idx={idx + 1} />}
      </ReactNativeModal>
    );
  };
 
  return (
    <modalsContext.Provider value={{ registerModals, open, close, closeAll }}>
      {children}
      {isModalsExist && <MoadlComponent idx={0} />}
    </modalsContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

each time I open another modal,

```
useEffect(() => {
      console.log({ idx });
}, []);
```

runs inside all nested from top to bottom (e.g.

```
{ idx : 2 }
{ idx : 1 }
{ idx : 0 }
```

), and of course, inside component logs run as well, which create an unnecessary heavy calculation

The weird thing is that my first and main suspect, `isModalsExist`, isn't the trigger as

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log({ isModalsExist });
}, [isModalsExist]);
```

runs only if the boolean indeed change, and anyhow if it was, I expecting the logs to be from bottom to top, not the opposite.

Any help appreciated, can't figure what I totally missing

Comment: You don't want to put the MoadlComponent into the ModalsProvider's body without wrapping it into a useEffect, because it reassigns a completely new function component each time the ModalsProvider re-renders.

Comment: Thanks @AndorPolgar, indeed refactoring the declaration did the trick :)

If you will post your comment as an answer I'll be happy to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to put the MoadlComponent into the ModalsProvider's body without wrapping it into a useEffect, because it reassigns a completely new function component each time the ModalsProvider re-renders.